# Управление через одного тг бота, несколькими другими ботами

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Разрабатываю бота на python + aiogram похожего на Nemiling

Задумка в том что есть главный бот, через которого люди создают своих ботов(Дочерних), то есть отправляют в главного: токен своего бота, название, и некоторый другие параметры.

Хотелось бы узнать как сделать так что бы после того как человек создал через главного бота, своего бота(Дочернего), он мог писать уже в только что созданного бота(Дочернего), например /start и дочерний бот, писал к примеру какой-нибудь текст

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что именно вы хотите?

Comment: Изменил вопрос, возможно так будет понятнее

Comment: Загоняешь дочерние ключи в список, берешь по одному токену и выгружаешь всю его очередь сообщений, отвечаешь на неё, затем берешь следящий токен и т.д...по кругу.
Или для каждого токена создаете свой поток(если ботов будет не очень много)